# What's the difference between returning a const object reference (getter), and just the string?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, return-value, return-type

I was going through the c++ website tutorials as a nice compliment to a college course I'm taking this semester (beginner). While learning about [copy constructors and destructors](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes2), I came across this section of code:

```
// destructors
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Example4 {
    string* ptr;
  public:
    // constructors:
    Example4() : ptr(new string) {}
    Example4 (const string& str) : ptr(new string(str)) {}
    // destructor:
    ~Example4 () {delete ptr;}
    // access content:
    const string& content() const {return *ptr;}
};

int main () {
  Example4 foo;
  Example4 bar ("Example");

  cout << "bar's content: " << bar.content() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Now, I understand the destructor part, but the getter for the string member confused me. Why return a reference (alias) to the object (string in this case)?

```
// access content:
const string& content() const {return *ptr;}
```

What is the difference between that, and just returning the string?

```
string content() const {
    return *ptr;
}
```

Is returning a const alias more efficient? Are you returning just the address of the string, or the string itself? What about when just returning the string, are you returning the entire string? Thanks.

Comment: If your course is telling you that `new` and `delete` are appropriate to "use objects", they are lying to you or trying to make you write Java. That should be `class Example4 { string str; public: Example4() {} Example4 (const string& str) : str(str) {} const string& content() const {return str;} };` (If at all, it has no behaviour). The best constructors are implicit.

Comment: allocating a `std::string` on the heap (using `new`) is **poor** coding practice, as `std::string` is already managing its memory (on the heap if long).

Answer (score 0):

Returning a string would be undesirable for two reasons:

- It means an unnecessary copy of the string is performed, which is bad for performance
- It also means that someone might attempt to modify the returned string, thinking that they modify the actual member of the class - `const` reference would not allow this, and trigger a compilation error.

Comment: On the other hand, returning a reference means the caller can form a dangling reference with no warnings.

Answer (score 0):

> the getter for the string member confused me.  Why return a
>   reference (alias) to the object (string in this case)?
>
> ```
> const string& content() const {return *ptr;}
> ```
>
> What is the difference between that [return a reference], 
>   and just returning the string?
>
> ```
> string content() const { return *ptr;}
> ```

And you might ask if there is a difference between that 
and returning only the pointer

```
const string* content() const { return ptr;}
```

---

- I find no advantage of one over the other(s).

Well, maybe consider the scenario where the string contains 26 million chars, you probably want to avoid copying that.

But there is another issue (or maybe 2) you should be aware of, if only to evaluate what you have learned here.

---

On Lubuntu 18.04, using g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27),  a string s, with no data,

```
std::string s; 
cout << sizeof(s) << "  " << s.size() << endl;
```

Reports the numbers "32  0".

---

```
std::string s ("01234567890123456789"); 
cout << sizeof(s) << "  " << s.size() << endl;
```

Reports values "32  20"

---

```
{
   std::string s;
   for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
   {
      for (char j='A'; j<='Z'; j++)
         s.push_back(j);
   }
   cout << "  " << sizeof(s) << "  " << s.size() << endl;
}
```

This reports the values "32  26000000"

- 1 million alphabets
- s is still only 32 bytes

From this, you may conclude a) that an instance of 'string' occupies 32 bytes regardless of data.  b) because all the data resides elsewhere  c) so some of the 32 bytes in a std::string instance is a pointer to where in dynamic memory the chars resides.

---

Hmmm.

If the obj instance is only 32 bytes, then you might ask why does Example4 use a pointer to place this SMALL object (the string instance) into the dynamic memory ... using 8 bytes to find 32, and then needing a second reference (of some pointer inside of the string instance) to reach the char's of Example4 string.

In the same way, a std::vector is 24 bytes (regardless of how many elements, and regardless of how big the elements). std::vector takes care of memory management, so that you don't have to.

Perhaps this lesson is meant to help you discover and evaluate what is in dynamic memory, and what is in automatic memory, to improve your choices.

The key idea, is that STL library containers handle dynamic memory for you, to greatly simplify your effort.

---

Or, perhaps the professor wants you to know more about the tools you are using.  The standard containers, in some ways, isolate you from how this stuff works.  Perhaps this assignment is to get a glimpse into what std::string does.

---

// here is some "g++ -std=c++17" code to single step through, illustrating several of the ideas

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::endl;

#include <sstream>
using std::stringstream;

#include <iomanip>
using std::setfill, std::setw;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <cstring>
using std::strlen;


class Example4
{
   string* ptr;
public:
   Example4() : ptr(new string) {}
   Example4 (const string& str) : ptr(new string(str)) {}
   ~Example4 () {delete ptr;}

   // access content:
   const string& content() const {return *ptr;}
   const string* contentP() const {return  ptr;}

   string show(string lbl)
      {
         stringstream ss;
         ss << "\n  " << lbl
            <<             "               .  5         4         3         2         1"
            << "\n                         . '09876543210987654321098765432109876543210987654321'"
            << "\n  " << "*ptr                   : '" << *ptr  << "'"
            << "\n  " << "(*ptr).size()          : " << (*ptr).size()
            << "\n  " << "  ptr->size()          : " <<   ptr->size()
            << "\n  " << "strlen((*ptr).c_str()) : " << strlen((*ptr).c_str())
            << "\n  " << "strlen(ptr->c_str())   : " << strlen(ptr->c_str())
            << "\n\n  " << "sizeof(*ptr)           : " << sizeof(*ptr)

            << "     @ 0x" << ptr << ',' // where ptr points to
            << "\n  " << "sizeof (ptr)           : " << sizeof(ptr)
            << "\n\n";
         return ss.str();
      }
};



class T996_t
{
public:
   int operator()() { return exec(); }

private: // methods

   int exec()
      {
         Example4 e4("Now is the time to answer all questions01234567890");

         cout << "\n  "  <<  e4.show("Example4")
              << "\n  '" <<  e4.content() << "'"
              << "\n  '" << *e4.contentP() << "'\n\n"
              << endl;

         {
            std::string s;
            cout << "  " << sizeof(s) << "  " << s.size() << endl;
         }

         {
            std::string s("01234567890123456789");
            cout << "  " << sizeof(s) << "  " << s.size() << endl;
         }

         {
            std::string s;
            for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
            {
               for (char j='A'; j<='Z'; j++)
                  s.push_back(j);
            }
            cout << "  " << sizeof(s) << "  " << s.size() << endl;
         }

         return 0;
      }

}; // class T996_t

int main(int, char**) { return T996_t()(); }
```

This code compiles and runs on my Lubuntu.  The compile command built by my make file starts with:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -m64 -ggdb
```